# Avast Sandbox vs C# приложение

Tags: c#, sandbox, антивирус

Есть приложение (пусть будет называться `Launcher.exe`) из одного `exe` файла, которое проверяет целостность другого приложения. Каждый раз, когда запускается новый билд приложения то `Avast` запускает его в `Sandbox'е`, что порождает массу ошибок последнего из-за ограниченных прав с которыми оно запускается. Мало того, при самообновлении на новую версию первый запуск `Launcher.exe` происходит через `Sandbox`. А запуск производится с дополнительными аргументами и возможна вероятность (пока не наблюдается) неполного выполнения сценария очистки кеша создаваемого приложением при самообновлении (временные файлы).

Есть ли возможность избежать такие проверки со стороны антивируса для приложения от `хоум девелопера`?

Comment: Самый простой вариант - приостанавливать работу антивируса на то время, пока вы балуетесь с приложением вашим.

Comment: Есть ещё проще вариант. Добавить в исключения антивируса. У меня была такая проблема, так и сделал.

Comment: А подпись сертификатом компилируемое приложение может изменить ситуацию, т.к. многие exe файлы Avast игнорирует, даже если они скачаны из неизвестных источников?

Comment: Для использования именно Аваст есть весомая причина, кроме его бесплатности?

Comment: Вопрос не в антивирусе, а в визуальных косяках и ошибках приложения вызванных им. Это у меня он стоит. Возможно, я единственных кто им пользуется и проблема проявляться будет только у меня. Но факт остаётся фактом. Просто интересно решение данного казуса. Предполагаю, что антивирус проверяет сертификат зашитый в приложение перед запуском его в `Sandbox'e`.

Comment: @Rootware не совсем так. Сам факт подписи приложения ни чего не меняет для антивируса, особенно если сертификат самоподписанный. Для него важно, что файлы были модифицированы с момента последнего запуска. А если при этом еще и сертификат нельзя проверить через удостоверяющий центр, то такому приложению прямая дорога в сандбокс.

Comment: @rdorn за многие годы пользования `Avast` заметил, что не все `exe` файлы он запускает через песочницу при первом запуске. Поэтому и решил спросить, вдруг кто знает наверняка.